# Convergence of a Fourier series to a point

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, convergence-divergence, fourier-series

Consider the function $f\left(x\right)=1+x$, $x \in \left[-\pi,\pi\right]$

I have calculated its Fourier series to be
$$f\left(x\right)=1+2\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\dfrac{\left(-1\right)^{n+1}}{n}\sin nx.$$

I need to determine whether the series converges at $x=\dfrac{\pi}{2}$, and if so, what it converges to.

Plugging $x=\dfrac{\pi}{2}$ into the Fourier series, I obtain
$$1+2\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\dfrac{\left(-1\right)^{n+1}}{n}\sin\left(\dfrac{n\pi}{2}\right).$$

For even $n$, $\sin\left(\dfrac{n\pi}{2}\right)=0$ and so the series converges to $f\left(x\right)=1$.

For odd $n$, $\sin\left(\dfrac{n\pi}{2}\right)=\sin\left(\dfrac{\left(2k-1\right)\pi}{2}\right)=(-1)^{k+1}$.

So the series converges to 
$$1+2\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\dfrac{\left(-1\right)^{2k}}{2k-1}\left(-1\right)^{k+1}=1+2\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\dfrac{\left(-1\right)^{3k+1}}{2k-1}.$$

I am not sure where to go from here.

Comment: It's easy to show the series converges; the argument you gave, with the hint in the other comment, shows that. That does not answer the question of what it converges to. You must be studying Fourier series. Presumably you've covered various tests that show that the Fourier series of a function converges to the function at a given point? One of those tests (a big one) shows that in fact the series converges to $f(\pi/2)$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Yes I am studying Fourier series. However I'm missing notes on tests for convergence of a Fourier Series. Perhaps you could elaborate on this big test?

Comment: Googling "Fourier series convergence tests" leads to more than you need to know: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_Fourier_series#Pointwise_convergence

Answer (score 1):

Your function satisfies the Dirichlet conditions and the periodic extension of $f$ over the real line is continuous at $x=\dfrac{\pi}{2}$, so its Fourier series converges to $f\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right) = 1 + \dfrac{\pi}{2}$.

If you wanted to check this explicitly, you would need to show that $$2\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\dfrac{\left(-1\right)^{3k+1}}{2k-1} = \dfrac{\pi}{2}$$

Which amounts to showing:
$$\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\dfrac{\left(-1\right)^{k+1}}{2k-1} = \sum^{\infty}_{k=0}\dfrac{\left(-1\right)^{k}}{2k+1} = \dfrac{\pi}{4}$$

This is true by Leibniz's formula, using an expansion of $arctan(1)$ which can be found on the following page: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_π](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_%CF%80) .

(See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_conditions for the Dirichlet conditions if you are not familiar with them.)